# What does this block of code do? Angular Firebase Authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, promise, rxjs

```
doRegister(value){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
     .then(res => {
       resolve(res);
     }, err => reject(err))
   })
 }
```

Could someone walk me through this code? The main things I'm confused is the structure of a Promise and then the code starting at .then.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
```

returns a Promise object. A promise is a way of executing asynchronous tasks. The `then()` method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

This example creates a promise which will be resolved if createUserWithEmailAndPassword is resolved and rejected if that other promise is rejected. So, the promise is wrapped in another promise which will behave the same.

I would simplify it to:

```
doRegister(value) {
   return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password);
 }
```

Returning the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` promise directly, this should behave the same.